# How to print diamond using '#' in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a diamond with one '#' symbol on the first and last lines, and two '#' symbols on each line in between, with a space in the middlemost line.

Stipulations: should be a function diamond(n) that prints a diamond with spaces and '#' symbols that is n rows and n characters wide.

I've tried this:

```
for i in range(n-1):
  print((n-i) * ' ' + (2*i+1) * '#')
for k in range(n-1, -1, -1):
  print((n-i) * ' ' + (2*i+1) * '#')
```

but I'm getting too many '#' symbols per line.

Expected outcome for diamond(5):

```
  #
 # #
#   #
 # #
  #
```

Comment: also, I have to use a nested for loops

Comment: Try `print('\n'.join([''.join([('*' if abs(x)+abs(y) == n//2+1 else ' ') for x in range(-n//2-1, n//2+2)]) for y in range(-n//2-1, n//2+2)]))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the quantity of spaces you need between the two octothorpes.  YOur first line has a single octo and no spaces between (duh!).  Then you need

```
line internal spaces
 2    1
 3    3
 4    5
 5    7
...
```

Since you've been able to figure out the previous linear relationships, I suspect you can get this one.

```
space_ct =    # your code here
print((n-i) * ' ' + '#' + space_ct * ' ' + '#')
```

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I just gave you four points on a line.  Apply the two-point formula for a linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
n=2
j=n-1
print(' '*(n)+'#')
for i in range(1, 2*n):
    if i>n:
        print(' '*(i-n)+'#'+' '*(2*j-1)+'#')
        j-=1
    else:
        print(' '*(n-i)+'#'+' '*(2*i-1)+'#')
if n>1:
    print(' '*n+'#')
```

**Output**

```
  #
 # #
#   #
 # #
  #
```

Comment: what about def print_diamond(n) where a diamond is printed with spaces and '#' symbols that is n rows and n chars wide?

Comment: I think you have to define all these things in your question first whatever you want. Also, you can try something on your own. The logic was the main which I gave you in the answer. Just a little advice to a fellow developer